# Accessing Object Property Directly thymeleaf

Tags: java, thymeleaf

Let's say I have a class `Factory` with 2 fields: `fName` and `fArea`. Is it possible to refer to these fields through a single object `f1` (an instance of `Factory`) added to either a `Model` or a `ModelAndView`? Resulting to something like this `${f.fArea}` (where `f` is the `String attributeName` argument of `addObject` method).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's possible.  That syntax is the basis of how thymeleaf expressions work...

```
// Controller
@GetMapping("/whatever")
public String whatever(Map<String, Object> model) {
    model.put("f", new Factory());
    return "whatever";
}

// Template
</span th:text="${f.fArea}" />
```

http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#variables